# Simulating a robot in construction field

Tags: simulation

I'm thinking about a research topic that involves robots used in civil engineering specifically dealing with steel structures of buildings. For example, lifting and placing steel structures.

If I choose to simulate the work of the robot in this area, like after designing the robot and the building, what is the best software that could offer this functionality? I would like to be able to simulate the movement of the robot and its interactions with the building and its material.

Is there a software that could serve this topic? Also it would be a bonus if the software could perform structural/reliability analysis.

By the way, I prefer to work on windows, but also no problem with another OS if recommended. And I have no price limit.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Could you please include what OS the software should run on and what your price limit would be for paid software?

Comment: Hello Izzy. Thank you! Well I prefer windows, but I could  use another OS if recommended. As for the price, I think there is no price limit because I will be working from university as PhD student and I think they might have some softwares available already. So, I will see all possible suggestions, and then consult with the IT specialist to download it. I updated my question :)